# What does hwclock output on a virtual box guest without guest additions

Tags: virtualbox

My host is Ubuntu and the hwclock is in sync with the system time:

```
mike@laptop:~$ sudo hwclock;date
Thu 15 Mar 2018 13:56:58 GMT  .655654 seconds
Thu 15 Mar 13:56:59 GMT 2018
```

But if I run these commands in a VirtualBox guest (within 1 second of running on the host) then the hwclock is not the time of the host hwclock:

```
[root@rhel65 ~]# hwclock;date
Thu 15 Mar 2018 04:06:27 GMT  -0.119648 seconds
Thu Mar 15 13:50:10 GMT 2018
```

and it is not just the "hours" that are not correct - it is the minutes and seconds as well, so what time is vbox providing to the guest for RTC when guest additions are not installed - I had assumed it would give the host RTC, irrespective of whether the vbox guest additions were installed or not.